# why breakpoints not hitting when debugging web service in debugging mode using soapUI and eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, web-services, debugging, soapui

I added breakpoints in soap web services and I used soapUI for testing  web service. When I was running web service in soapui then breakpoints not hitting in eclipse. Why breakpoints are not hitting?

Comment: Are you using SoapUI inside or outside of eclipse? If you're using outside of eclipse you need to to connect the eclipse debugger to it, If you're running SoapUI inside eclipse in debug mode and it's not stopping at breakpoints, but you are sure it should stop, then it could be a bug in the plugin - describe how you are running it

Comment: The SoapUI Eclipse plugin has been abandoned a long time ago. If you are trying to debug your Groovy test steps, then AFAIK this is not possible. I did some research on this; see this: https://siking.wordpress.com/2012/03/20/debugging-soapui-groovy-scripts-in-eclipse/